# Hide or Remove the Additional tab on Woocommerce checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I want to remove the additional tab from checkout step.I tried the followoing code ,its remove the notes field but the tab still exist.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'bbloomer_remove_checkout_order_notes' );

function bbloomer_remove_checkout_order_notes( $fields ) {
     unset($fields['order']['order_comments']);
     return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_enable_order_notes_field', '__return_false' );
```

I tried by using css.That hide the tab and its data but didn't move the tab to next on click.So i think it will be good if i found some filter type code.Thanks

Comment: you mean you want to remove the second column ? and make the first one 100% ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif  Basically there are three coloumns.1) Billing info (2) Additional tab (3) Payment and review.I want to remove the additional one while leave the other two.

Comment: can you show your site ? i don't think applying any filter will do this, you need to either update the template file of woocommerce or apply a CSS

Comment: @TemaniAfif you can check my site on this link.http://demo2.nminteractive.co/kimlipe/programs/.You can add to cart any product then goto checkout .There you will see the tabs.

Comment: as expected, your checkout page is not the classic one, so your theme is creating a custom one ... you should locate it in your theme files and change the file inside your child theme

Comment: I didn't create as i am child theme developer.May be Avada theme have this option.Do you have idea which file creating this issue ? Thanks

Comment: yes for sure it comes with theme and i cannot tell you exactly which file or option, you may give the access of the site i can have a quick look if it's ok with you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156171/discussion-between-temani-afif-and-mahmood-rehman).